# How to set dispatcher / thread pool for akka http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have a question regarding akka-http. I have developed a service which is spinning up different actors and besides of some other task some of the actors are also doing external http calls to different endpoints via the akka-http Http().singleRequest function. I want to isolate the Http calls via a separate dispatcher pool/configuration, but I can't find a way to define the dispatcher. For other actors I can define it via the .withDispatcher() method. Akka-http is running via akka streams as far as I know (via the actor materializer), but how can I define the dispatcher for the Http().singleRequest function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define your dispatcher in your conf file.
for more information please read akka documentation from the given link.
Dispatchers implement the ExecutionContext interface and can thus be used to run Future invocations etc.

actually after defining the dispatcher, you can use that dispatcher for the actor's which are doing the calls for external API and give them the execution context via dispatcher.

> https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html

it has structure like this:

```
my-dispatcher {
  # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
  type = Dispatcher
  # What kind of ExecutionService to use
  executor = "fork-join-executor"
  # Configuration for the fork join pool
  fork-join-executor {
    # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-min = 2
    # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-max = 10
  }
  # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
  # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
  # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
  throughput = 100
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Yes, I know that I can define dispatcher in the config file, but how can I assign the dispatcher only to akka http and not to the other actors? As I said, I want to isolate the Http().singleRequest calls from the rest of the actor system, so I don't want to change the default dispatcher for all actors.

Comment: actor needs execution context for calls by creating a new execution context for your actor you can assign that dispatcher for the specific actors. at the time of calls like ask you will have to pass implicit execution context which will be your dispatcher.

Comment: and if you want these actors to be in a separate actor system then also at the time of creation of the actor system you will have to give the execution context that time use your defined dispatcher.

Comment: Ok, so currently I don't have a dedicated Http actor, which is doing the Http calls. So if I want to have the Http().singleRequest calls made by a separate thread pool, I have to put these calls into a separate actor (which gets initialized with the .withDispatcher function) and the actor, which wants to send out Http calls (but should be in a different thread pool) would need to send a message to the Http actor to do the call, correct?

Comment: @Lothium the different dispatcher means it will have a different thread pool because while defining your dispatcher you will define the thread pool also. And yes you are right while crating the actor use withDispatcher which will assign your thread dispatcher to that actor. you can print the dispatcher by contex.dipatcher or system.dipatcher